# how can i initilise string of arrays in dynamically

Tags: c#, string, dynamic

I am new to C#, I want to initialise string of arrays dynamically, how can I achieve it? i.e. first I initialised...

```
string[] filepaths;

    public void btnGetFiles_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


       try
       {

            filepaths[] = Directory.GetFiles(@txtGetFile.Text,"*.txt");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

In `filepaths[]`it is not getting the directory files. Please help..

Comment: It should work. Is txtGetFile.Text pointing to the correct directory? Also the @ is not needed.

Comment: Can you tell us what exception is being thrown ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
filepaths[] = Directory.GetFiles(@txtGetFile.Text,"*.txt");
```

Remove the brackets and the (optional) @ symbol from the control name:

```
filepaths = Directory.GetFiles(txtGetFile.Text,"*.txt");
```

`filepaths` is your variable name, so you address it by that.

Comment: To clarify, using the @ symbol is not an error, it's just not needed, and not often used.

Comment: @SWeko - the @ symbol, AFAIK its only used to escape string literals, not when they come from a property?

Comment: The @ symbol allows you to use a reserved word for an [identifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664670.aspx), i.e. `class` is not a valid identifier, but `@class` is. I've seen several code generators use the `@` because you could have, for example, a database column named "bool".

Comment: But should it be used for the control name?

Comment: As far as the compiler is concerned `@txtGetFile`, and `txtGetFile` are the exact same thing, so yes, it can be used, and no, it shouldn't be used :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the `[]`, they are only necessary when you declare an array.

```
filepaths = Directory.GetFiles(txtGetFile.Text,"*.txt");
```

Answer (score 1):

You must not use the array brackets on the **filepaths** variable, the brackets are used only @ declaration on the declaring type, Ex:

```
Type[] yourVarName;
```